# Py3k: What's more pythonic - one import with commas or many imports?

Tags: python, coding-style, python-3.x

What is more pythonic ?

```
import os
import sys
import getopt
...
```

or

```
import os,sys,getopt,...
```

?

Comment: `import os, sys, getopt,...`  > `import os,sys,getopt,...` for any python version.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

From [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports):

Imports should usually be on separate lines, e.g.:

Yes:

```
import os
import sys
```

No:

```
import sys, os
```

it's okay to say this though:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
```